# Adding a Video Background to iOS app signup like Instagram and Vine

Tags: ios, swift, video, background-image, ios9

I have created an app which loads up and has a Login / Signup page etc using swift. Currently I have an image as a background but would like to add code so there is a gif / mov playing in the background like in apps like vine or instagram.

How can I integrate the video in with my current code? I am also very new to this so have been following tutorials. Also if anyone knows how I can remove the parse logo, that would also be helpful.

The video appears but in front of the UI on my storyboard! How can I get them to appear in front of the background GIF?

Below is my code that I currently have for my Sign In view controller.

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class SignInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var userName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var errorLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()

    let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("beachwater", ofType: "gif")
    let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

    let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
    webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL(string: "")!)
    webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
    self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)


    userName.delegate = self
    password.delegate = self
}


@IBAction func signInTouched(sender: UIButton) {

    let signin = SignIn(user: userName.text!, pass: password.text!)

    do {
        try signin.signInUser()
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    } catch let error as Error {
        errorLabel.text = error.description
    } catch {
        errorLabel.text = "Sorry something went\n wrong please try again"
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}

}
```

Comment: Just add a webview to the background and include a gif in your project that you open in your webview.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The following code allows you to add a video background for your view controller.

It is written in `Swift` and plays `mp4` video files.

For `Swift 5`.

```
import AVFoundation

class VideoBackgroundController: UIViewController {
    var avPlayer: AVPlayer!
    var avPlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer!
    var paused: Bool = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        let theURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource:"my_video_file", withExtension: "mp4")

        avPlayer = AVPlayer(url: theURL!)
        avPlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: avPlayer)
        avPlayerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        avPlayer.volume = 0
        avPlayer.actionAtItemEnd = .none

        avPlayerLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        view.layer.insertSublayer(avPlayerLayer, at: 0)

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                           selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd(notification:)),
                                           name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                           object: avPlayer.currentItem)
    }

    @objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: Notification) {
        let p: AVPlayerItem = notification.object as! AVPlayerItem
        p.seek(to: .zero)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        avPlayer.play()
        paused = false
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        avPlayer.pause()
        paused = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great. Question. Did you have any issues getting it to load right away? Mine currently just pops in after a couple seconds

Comment: How I can add a transparency layer?

Comment: This is awesome, only current issue is it pauses playing music, on music play the video pauses - but this is probably expected due to the AVPlayer implmentation

Comment: @JCarlos For add gradient, comment `//view.backgroundColor = .clear` and add [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54556076/5869217)

Answer (score 2):

This works, replace all of the code that you just put there with this:

```
     let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("beach_water", ofType: "gif")
     let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

     let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
     webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL(string: "")!)
     webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
     self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)
```

That is all tested and works 100%

EDIT Swift 3 and have the Gif in the background:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "beach_water", ofType: "gif")
let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)
let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
webViewBG.load(gif! as Data, mimeType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL(string: "")! as URL)
webViewBG.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
webViewBG.layer.zPosition = -2.0
self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)
```

Comment: So there are no errors with this code which is excellent! But I am now getting the problem that the gif won't appear behind my text. It is just blank. I am using Parse for the sign in so I wonder if it is to do with that and I need another line of code to show the video behind the buttons. I will put a screenshot up so you can see my results.

Comment: it works when I put it alone in a view controller with nothing else in it! Hmm I am confused as to why it won't go into the background.

Comment: Ok, make sure the code is the first line in the viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: No luck. I think it didn't work because it is a PFLogInViewController for parse use...

Comment: so this code is great but now it won't appear behind all my other items in the storyboard :/

Comment: The video appears but in front of the UI of my storyboard! How can I get the UI to appear in front of the background GIF? I have amended the code so you can see what I now have.

Comment: Set the z position like this: webViewBG.zposition = 2.0

Comment: Where would that go exactly?

Comment: Before you add the webViewBG to the subview

Comment: Thanks for your help. Figured it out. The code needs to be slightly different... webViewBG.layer.zPosition = -2.0

Answer (score 0):

Really simple, first drag your gif into your Assets.xcassets.
Second get the file in code(probably in a configure view method.

```
    var filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(“YourImageNameHere”, ofType: “gif”)
    var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)
```

3. Create a UIWebView and add the GIF NSData as its data source.

   ```
   var webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)
   webViewBG.loadData(gif, MIMEType: “image/gif”, textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)
   webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false;
   self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)
   ```

And there you go, just make sure to have the webView behind your Buttons and other UIElements

Comment: Seems simple but where in my code would that all go?

Comment: In the replace the background Image with this code in the viewDidLoad

Comment: This is the error I am getting... Nil is not compatible with expected argument type 'String'.

Comment: On what line was that?

Comment: Both of these lines have problems:           var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath)    
                                                                                     webViewBG.loadData(gif, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: nil, baseURL: nil)

Comment: Try var gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filepath!) that should fix it

Comment: now it says; use of unresolved identifier 'filepath'

Comment: I have provided a screenshot above to show where I have put it and the problems.

Comment: Oh your file path can't have .gif on it because you use oftype: gif so that automatically adds that onto it.

Comment: Deleted the .gif and it still has the error. I have replaced the screenshot

Comment: Try this: You need to implement do try catch error handling. Try like this:  if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Chapters", ofType: "txt"){     do {         let stringFromFile = try String(contentsOfFile:path, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)         var chapters: [String] = stringFromFile.componentsSeparatedByString("@")         chapters.removeAtIndex(0)     } catch {         print((error))     }  }

Comment: But fill in your file path and your details

Comment: included a new screenshot. Still same error. I wonder if it is a bug!

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I will write it out for you, all tested and everything

Answer (score 0):

This is the complete solution. The negative z position is important!

```
let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Lake", ofType: "gif")

let gif = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath!)

let webViewBG = UIWebView(frame: self.view.frame)

webViewBG.loadData(gif!, MIMEType: "image/gif", textEncodingName: "UTF-8", baseURL: NSURL(string: "")!)

webViewBG.userInteractionEnabled = false
webViewBG.layer.zPosition = -2.0
self.view.addSubview(webViewBG)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! To add gradient :

```
let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradient.colors = [self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#141414").cgColor,self.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "#323232").cgColor]
    gradient.locations = [0.0,1.0]
    gradient.opacity = 0.8
    gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 0.0)
    gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    gradient.frame = viewLogin.layer.frame
    viewLogin.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

hexStringToUIColor method :

```
var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
        cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)
    }

    if ((cString.count) != 6) {
        return UIColor.gray
    }

    var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
    Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt32(&rgbValue)

    return UIColor(
        red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
        green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
        blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
        alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Swift `UIView` subclass called `SDLoopingVideoView` that plays and loops any compatible `AVPlayer` video file and automatically scales it to fill the view. It can be entirely setup in Interface Builder This work great as a video background. You can find it on Github here: [SDLoopingVideoView](https://github.com/SolsmaHawk/SDLoopingVideoView)